# how import Object and String of Json in Mysql with php?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want import json data to mysql by php code.
I have a json file and include many Object and string.

```js
{
  "card": "2",
  "numbers": {
    "Conway": [1, 11, 21, 1211, 111221, 312211],
    "Fibonacci": [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
  },
  "numbers2": {
    "Conway": [1, 11, 21, 1211, 111221, 312211],
    "Fibonacci": [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
  }
}
```

my php file

```php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "dbname"); //Connect PHP to MySQL Database
$query = '';
$table_data = '';
$filename = "urljsonfile.json";
$data = file_get_contents($filename); //Read the JSON file in PHP
$array = json_decode($data, true); //Convert JSON String into PHP Array
foreach($array as $row) //Extract the Array Values by using Foreach Loop
{
    $query .= "UPDATE tblname SET clumnname='".$row["Conway"]."' WHERE id=2; ";  // Make Multiple Insert Query 
   $table_data .= '
            <tr>
                <td>'.$row["Conway"].'</td>
            </tr>
           '; //Data for display on Web page
}

if(mysqli_multi_query($connect, $query)) //Run Mutliple Insert Query
{
    echo '<h3>Imported JSON Data</h3><br />';
    echo ' 
      <table class="table table-bordered">
          <tr>
              <th width="45%">Name</th>
          </tr>
     ';
    echo $table_data;  

    echo '</table>';
}
```

I want import only  Conway(array) in number2(object)  to mysql
how do it?

Comment: In query, when you have to encode the data. like $query .= "UPDATE tblname SET clumnname='".json_encode($row["Conway"])."' WHERE id=2;

Comment: I use $array = json_decode($data, true);  and then foreach($array as $row)

Comment: You simply want to loop over `$array['numbers2']['Conway']` …

Comment: thanks @misorude . solved

Comment: please help me now how to plus fix number to this json value.

Answer (score 0):

I solved . thanks @misorude      `$array['numbers2']['Conway']`

now how remove 'comma' in number value?
for example if my json file some like :

```
    {
  "card": "2",
  "numbers": {
    "Conway": [234,872],
    "Fibonacci": [12]
  },
  "numbers2": {
    "Conway": [123,678],
    "Fibonacci": [12]
  }

}
```

[Conway]  remove comma